# Run mask,Faster,and YOLO v4 on the same code with different GPUs

Tags: tensorflow

there is my code

i firstly tried the cuda visible devices but it didnt worked then i tried :

with tf.device(gpus[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrTmu.png).name):

not working either for me

when GPU's is free : [nvidia-smi image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEagp.png)

when i started the code my GPU's memory :[nvidia-smi image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrTmu.png)

i deleted some parts of code cause its not relevant what i ask this code didnt pops error when i started but i couldnt split the code between two GPU's can you pls help me?

```
"""import os

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID" 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,1"""

import pyzed.sl as sl
import cv2
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation
import time
import threading
import numpy as np
from cgi import print_arguments


import tensorflow as tf


tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
gpus1= tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus1[1], True)
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus1[0], True)
gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
import serial
import time
from sklearn.datasets import make_sparse_spd_matrix





while 1 :        
    with tf.device(gpus[1].name):
            res = segmentation_model.segmentFrame(frame, show_bboxes=False)
            frame = res[1]
            print("flag1")
            cv2.imshow("mask",frame)
            
            cv2.waitKey(1)
    with tf.device(gpus[0].name):
            image =frame 
            image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_rgb, axis=0)

            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})
        #------------------------------------------------
            try: 
                conf_threshold = 0.5
                nms_threshold = 0.45
                image_shape = image.shape[:2]
                filtered_scores = [scores[0][i] for i in np.where(scores[0] > conf_threshold)]
                filtered_boxes = [boxes[0][i] for i in np.where(scores[0] > conf_threshold)]
                filtered_classes = [classes[0][i] for i in np.where(scores[0] > conf_threshold)]
                if len(filtered_scores[0]) != 0:
                    # NMS thresholding
                    indices, count = apply_non_max_suppression(filtered_boxes[0], filtered_scores[0], nms_threshold, 200)
                    selected_indices = indices[:count]

                    ## Getting the final boxes
                    final_boxes = filtered_boxes[0][selected_indices]
                    final_scores = filtered_scores[0][selected_indices]
                    final_classes = filtered_classes[0][selected_indices]


                    final_boxes = [denormalize_box(box, image_shape) for box in final_boxes]
                # final_boxes = [x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]
            #-------------------------------------------------
                # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
                vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    image,
                    np.squeeze(boxes),
                    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                    np.squeeze(scores),
                    category_index,
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                    line_thickness=8,
                    min_score_thresh=0.9)
            #-------------------------------------
                class_and_box = []
                for i in range(len(final_boxes)):
                    if ( final_scores[i]>0.90):
                        case = {final_classes[i] : final_boxes[i]}
                        class_and_box.append(case)

                #print(class_and_box)    
                def kutu_orta_nokta(liste):
                    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = liste
                    x, y = ((xmin+xmax)/2, (ymin+ymax)/2)
                    center = int(x), int(y)
                    cv2.circle(image, center, radius=10, color=(255, 0, 255), thickness=-1)

                    return center

                sag_liste= []
                orta_liste = []
                sol_liste= []

             
            cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            print('[Info] Time Taken: {} | FPS: {}'.format(time.time() - timer, 1 / (time.time() - timer)),
                    end='\r')
```

Comment: Hi @Ugur, you can use tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"]) to train on multiple devices. For more details please refer to this [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#mirroredstrategy). Thank You.